# Define a global color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor

I want to define a global colour that I can reuse for a downstate for various custom ui cells

Not sure if this is the correct way to do this but..

I've defined a Class called lightGreyUIColor which has this .h file -

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface lightGreyUIColor : UIColor
+ (UIColor*)lightGreyBGColor;

@end
```

and this . m file -

```
#import "lightGreyUIColor.h"

@implementation lightGreyUIColor

+ (UIColor*)lightGreyBGColor {
return [UIColor colorWithRed:241.0/255.0 green:241/255.0 blue:241/255.0 alpha:1];
}

@end
```

I have included the lightGreyUIColor.h file in the implementation file for the tableview and tried to reference it as folows -

```
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGreyBGColor];
```

Which just produces a no known class or method error for lightgreyBGColor, where am I going wrong and is there a better way to implement a global style than this?

Comment: whats wrong with a macro

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should create a category, not a subclass. This will extend the UIColor class, and add your colors to it.

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIColor (CustomColors)

+ (UIColor *)myColorLightGreyBGColor;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "UIColor+CustomColors.h"

@implementation UIColor (CustomColors)



+ (UIColor *)myColorLightGreyBGColor {

    static UIColor *lightGreyBGColor;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        lightGreyBGColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:241.0 / 255.0 
                                           green:241.0 / 255.0
                                            blue:241.0 / 255.0 
                                           alpha:1.0];
    });

    return lightGreyBGColor;
}

@end
```

By defining your colors this way, and #importing the category, you can apply this custom color the way you were already trying to.

Comment: I woul add a dispatch once together with a static variable. In this way the color won't be created each time...

Comment: You should prefix your category methods to avoid future collisions with methods Apple might add

Comment: cool - so I could use this same appraoch to define all dynamic colors within our app?  Could these colors be changed dynamically with this approach - ie if the user selected a different color scheme?

Comment: @Dancer You would want to define all your colors within the category as demonstrated above and then dynamically apply which color is actually used based on the theme, etc..

Comment: @0x7fffffff can you please explain the advantage of making category in this particular case instead of using macro? I mean i want to know benefits of using this approach.

Comment: @amar Type safety when using the new color for one, but mainly because creating the color this way will create one static reference to the color object, whereas the macro will essentially copy paste the `[UIColor colorWith...];` everywhere the macro is referenced during preprocessing.

Answer (score 10):

How about a macro?

```
#define DEFAULT_COLOR_BLUE [UIColor colorWithRed:.196 green:0.3098 blue:0.52 alpha:1.0]
```

Put it in your appname_Prefix.pch file or more likely a header file included in your prefix file

And it will be like:

```
cell.backgroundColor = DEFAULT_COLOR_BLUE;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your class name is `lightGreyUIColor`

Hence you need to use it as

```
cell.backgroundColor = [lightGreyUIColor lightGreyBGColor];
```

Or you need to create a category on `UIColor`.

---

EDIT:

Your code `[UIColor lightGreyBGColor]` tries to search for the method in `UIColor` itself, however you have subclassed `UIColor` by `lightGrayUIColor`.

As you are calling, it looks like you intended for a category.

*Side Note: ClassName should be captial as `LightGreyUIColor`.*

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a category. Read about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html)

In your case, you would have something like
UIColor+Grey.h

```
@interface UIColor (Grey) 

+(UIColor*) lightGreyBGColor;
@end
```

UIColor+Grey.m

```
#import "UIColor+Grey.h"

@implementation UIColor (Grey)

+(UIColor*) lightGreyBGColor {
     //define color
}
```

Then, in your controller, you would invoke it as:

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGreyBGColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating this, you can now create custom colours in Asset Catalog which are then visible in Interface Builder. See 
https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev10510b1f7

Click the + in Asset Catalog and choose New Color Set:

[image: Color Asset Catalog]

and in Interface Builder...

[image]

Comment: Also in WWDC here 
https://devblog.xero.com/managing-ui-colours-with-ios-11-asset-catalogs-16500ba48205